# PrestaShop 1.6: able to add product through Webservices API in localhost, but not in live server

Tags: api, prestashop

In PrestaShop 1.6: I am able to add product through Webservices API in localhost, but not in live server

I am getting this error "Uncaught exception 'PrestaShopWebserviceException' with message 'This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 500. That means: Internal Server Error.' in" while executing the below script in linux server for live site, but same works fine localhost, what could be the issue? yes of course I did change the PS_SHOP_PATH and PS_WS_AUTH_KEY value for live site.

```html
<?php
define('DEBUG', true);
define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', true);

define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://localhost/prestashop');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'your-key-here');


 
require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
 

 $xml_product = $webService->get(array('resource' => 'products?schema=blank'));
 $resources_product = $xml_product->children()->children();

 
$resources_product->id_manufacturer ='1';
$resources_product->id_supplier ='1';
$resources_product->id_category_default ='3';
//$resources_product->new ='1';
$resources_product->cache_default_attribute;
$resources_product->id_default_image;
$resources_product->id_default_combination;
$resources_product->id_tax_rules_group;
//$resources_product->position_in_category; 
$resources_product->manufacturer_name; 
//$resources_product->quantity="3"; 
$resources_product->type;
$resources_product->id_shop_default;
$resources_product->reference='SKUID45';
$resources_product->supplier_reference;
$resources_product->location;
$resources_product->width;
$resources_product->height; 
$resources_product->depth; 
$resources_product->weight;
$resources_product->quantity_discount; 
$resources_product->ean13;
$resources_product->upc;
$resources_product->cache_is_pack;
$resources_product->cache_has_attachments;
$resources_product->is_virtual;
$resources_product->on_sale;
$resources_product->online_only;
$resources_product->ecotax;
$resources_product->minimal_quantity;
$resources_product->price='20.00';
$resources_product->wholesale_price;
$resources_product->unity;
$resources_product->unit_price_ratio; 
$resources_product->additional_shipping_cost;
$resources_product->customizable;
$resources_product->text_fields;
$resources_product->uploadable_files;
$resources_product->active='1';
$resources_product->redirect_type;
$resources_product->id_product_redirected;
$resources_product->available_for_order;
$resources_product->available_date; 
$resources_product->condition ='new'; 
$resources_product->show_price; 
$resources_product->indexed ='1';
$resources_product->visibility = 'both';
$resources_product->advanced_stock_management;
$resources_product->date_add;
$resources_product->date_upd;
$resources_product->meta_description->language ='Product Meta Description';
$resources_product->meta_keywords->language='Product Meta keywords';
$resources_product->meta_title->language='Product Meta Title';
$resources_product->link_rewrite->language='product-url-key'; 
$resources_product->name->language='Product Name'; 
$resources_product->description->language='Product Description';
$resources_product->description_short->language='Product Short Description ';
$resources_product->available_now->language='30/10/14'; 
$resources_product->available_later->language;
$resources_product->associations->categories->addChild('category')->addChild('id', 3);


$xml_product = $webService->add(array('resource' => 'products', 'postXml' => $xml_product->asXML())); 
 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://localhost/prestashop/api/');
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
But as i said in first line, "I am able to add product through Webservices API in localhost, but not in live server"

in localhost everything works fine, add , edit, image upload, qty edit.

Comment: Enable your Webservices API in live server, replace localhost for your ip live server and change your api key for you api key in live server.

Comment: $livesite=0;  // 0 for local, 1 for server 

if($livesite==0){
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://localhost/prestashop');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'localhost-API-key-here');
}
else{
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://www.example.com');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'live-server-api-key-here');

}


i use above code to toggle between localhost and live server, so about the key and path there is no issue, also in both localhost and live server, all permission has been granted for those API key.